# Node server to run front-end packages

Tags: node.js, npm

I work with a server that does not have nodeJS.
I would like to use some front-end packages like request package.
Does I need to have node running on server to use those frontend packages?

This is for a Apache - MySQL - PHP server running on Debian-8 system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `request` module requires multiple Node APIs, like `http` and `https`, as you can see [in this file](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/request.js). This makes the module unsuitable for front-end use.

There are however alternatives. You can use [the native `fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), or a "webpack/browserify-compatible" module, like this one : https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-request.

This one can be bundled using a bundling tool, like Webpack or Browserify.

Comment: Thank you! This gives me a starting point for searching! The project I'm in charge of is using gulp ... I'll try to find packages compatible with this. If there is any tip, I appreciate it!